# Is it possible to disable emojs in Telegram desktop?

Tags: telegram-messenger

I do not use emojis, but they are forever being triggered accidentally by my mouse movements - and I have to cancel them to be able to read the comment I am responding to. I have asked the question in Telegram, but Telegram never answers my questions.

Comment: Pressing ESC gets rid not only of the emoj 'tool' but closes the particular chat that was open - so that is NOT satisfactory.

Comment: The REPLACE EMOJ setting is already unticked - yet the emoj tool stays active (and irritating).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, solved it by installing [another version of telegram desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/): they have one crossplatform and one specifically for macos. The one for macos only has this issue, while the crossplatform one has separate toggles for suggests and autoselect of emojis, when they are both toggled off, there is no emoji suggest at all.

Comment: Seasons Greetings. The URL above links to the same telegram I already use - which prompts emojs at the slightest 'false move' of the mouse.

Comment: I agree with Sebastian. As far as I can see, there is no crossplatform version, just separate Win, Linux and OSX version. I've got the Windows version, and the separate toggles for autoselect and suggest are there, and they are both turned off. Nevertheless the extremely annoying large window with emojies folds out every so often when I happen to move my mouse over the emoji icon, covering the whole chat area and as long as the mouse pointer is over it, it stays.